# Foreach loop & Double array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this double array I wrote (array within an array containing some information).
Below as you'll see I used a for each loop to display each set of logins.

```
 $servers = array(
 1 => array('server1','username1','password1','port1'),
 2 => array('server2','username2','password1','port2'),
 3 => array('server3','username3','password1','port3')
 );
 foreach ($servers as $count => $servers_array)
  {
   foreach ($servers_array as $num => $value)
  {
   echo $servers_array[0].":".$servers_array[1].":".$servers_array[2].":".$servers_array[3]."\n";
 }
}
```

The output of the above is

```
server1:username1:password1:port1
server1:username1:password1:port1
server1:username1:password1:port1
server1:username1:password1:port1
server2:username2:password1:port2
server2:username2:password1:port2
server2:username2:password1:port2
server2:username2:password1:port2
server3:username3:password1:port3
server3:username3:password1:port3
server3:username3:password1:port3
server3:username3:password1:port3
```

As you can see above it echo's out each set of logins 3 times. I need each set echoed just once each.

Anyone understand?

Comment: No need to add tags to title of question. They are all listed separately.

Comment: "As you can see above it echo's out each set of logins 3 times". It's 4 actually.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove your inner `foreach`.

```
<?php

 $servers = array(
 1 => array('server1','username1','password1','port1'),
 2 => array('server2','username2','password1','port2'),
 3 => array('server3','username3','password1','port3')
 );
 foreach ($servers as $count => $servers_array)
 {
     echo $servers_array[0].":".$servers_array[1].":".$servers_array[2].":".$servers_array[3]."\n";
 }
```

**Result**

```
server1:username1:password1:port1
server2:username2:password1:port2
server3:username3:password1:port3
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/6RcCAkga)

Comment: You're kidding me right? aha I feel soo stupid. I actually did try it within the single foreach but due to the double array for some reason it was only spitting out one set of logins. Thanks!!

Comment: No worries. I was actually thinking you may have wanted to iterate through the inner array to create the output.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your first foreach.

```
foreach ($servers as $servers_array) {
    echo $servers_array[0].":".$servers_array[1].":".$servers_array[2].":".$servers_array[3]."\n";
}
```

In fact you want to have an array of indexes inside the loop, therefore you just need one foreach.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
<?php
$servers = array(
   1 => array('server1','username1','password1','port1'),
   2 => array('server2','username2','password1','port2'),
   3 => array('server3','username3','password1','port3')
   );

   foreach ($servers as $count => $servers_array)
   {
     echo "<br />";
     foreach ($servers_array as $num => $value)
       {
          echo $value . ":";
       }
    }
 ?>
```